Can tubeless inserts be used with MTB tyres on narrower rims
I bought an older XC mountain bike and as it has carbon-fibre rims I thought about protecting them against hitting  a stone or a sharp edge with inserts. However I realized that most of them require at least 25 mm of wrim width and mybike only has 22 mm (still well within the ETRTO limits for a 2.25" tyre). There are some gravel-ones that are for narrower rims, but they are specified for the relatively narrow tyres (e.g., Vittoria Air-Liner Gravel for 32 - 42 mm) and not for a 2.25" MTB tyre. Are there any liners for MTB tyres on narrower rims or would it make any sense to try  some gravel ones for a wider tyre than they were designed for?

The second half of your question is a bit of a shopping question, but I can't see why you'd have any issues running a gravel-style insert. You won't enjoy as much of the air volume reduction effect that inserts can provide, but considering you're using them for rim protection and not performance improvement, that's probably not a big deal. Gravel rims for those tire widths are usually in the 20-25mm range so you're good in that regard.
However, I question the need to use protective inserts in the first place. How often are you smashing your rim on stuff? Yes, it's true that older carbon rims are a little weaker regarding impact loads than their modern counterparts--many new rims have extra thick hookless side walls compared to older hooked ones. They're still very strong though, and installing inserts might not be worth the effort, cost, and increase in rotating unsprung mass.

I did actually manage to irreversibly deform my alloy rim on my gravel bike. Maybe a carbon rim would survive, I do not know. It is concerning when the air pressure is low on the start or when the tyre burps.

@VladimirFГероямслава If you regularly have tire burps, that probably indicates a different issue altogether. But okay, in that case maybe it is worth having the inserts as a peace of mind thing.

I never said I had them... And that rim incident was with a different bike anyway, this one is new and a different category. But I think all World Cup racers carry inserts these days and they have a reason to do so I think.
